# How to get parameter back from method called in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios

How do you invoke something like this from C/C++ etc:

Implementation:

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    a += b;
    return a;
}
```

Call:

```
int newNumber = foo(1,2);
```

I think know this part:

Implementation:

```
-(int) foo: (int)a addTo: (int)b
{
    a += b;
    return a;
}
```

Call: ???

But how do you call this method in another method of the same class and retrieve that a?

I apologize in advance is this is blatantly in documentation or in another question - guess I need a little extra help. : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective C methods are called on a class instance (as in your case) or on class, like this:

```
int res = [self foo:1 addTo:2];
```

Or if it is a method of other object:

```
int res = [theObject foo:1 addTo:2];
```

Comment: Thanks for helpin' out a noob. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `[self foo:1 addTo:2];`